# Navigation safe args issue on navigating back to fragment

Tags: android, navigation, android-safe-args

I am using Navigation and safe arg to redirect user from fragment A to B. Fragment B further redirects user to fragment C based on the arguments passed from A to B. Now problem is when I am pressing back from fragment C fragment B gets recreated but still arguments that I passed previously I am getting again and again. So it creates one type of loop A - B - C - B - C - B - C

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please share code and nav_graph